# Creating a Bitmap from RGB video frames in Android

Tags: android

I have RGB video frames coming from native code, I have read somewhere its possible to convert RGB format frames into Bitmaps, Can anybody please help in telling how to achieve this in the application side (JAVA layer) in Android??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, size.width,size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```